# XLXSWriter Write grouped data to multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have a spreadsheet with Supervisor names and their employees. I need to group the data by supervisor and create a separate spreadsheet for each supervisor that contains each of their employees and some related info. I also need to format each of these worksheets and and some formulas.

I can create multiple spreadsheets with the grouped data using .to_excel, but can't figure a way to add format and formulas.

```
for group_name, group in gb:
    group.to_excel(r'C:\PATH'.format(group_name), sheet_name = 'Review', index=False, startrow = 0)
```

I can create multiple workbooks using the group_name with xlxswriter but I can only get data to write to the files by pushing the dataframe into tuples and then each spreadsheet populates with all of the data instead of the grouped data.

```
for group_name, group in gb:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(group_name + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Review')
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Sup Name')
    worksheet.write('B1', 'SupNo')
    worksheet.write('C1', 'Full Name')
    worksheet.write('D1', 'EENO')
    row = 1
    col = 0
    for SupName, SupNo, fullname, eeno in (tuples):
        worksheet.write_string(row, col, SupName)
        worksheet.write_number(row, col+1, SupNo)
        worksheet.write_string(row, col+2, fullname)
        worksheet.write_number(row, col+3, eeno)
        row += 1
    workbook.close()
```

Trying to figure out how to create multiple workbooks, based on groups, with the grouped data. I also tried creating tuple groups but I get an error indicating there are too many values to unpack.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I gave up pursuing this angle. I have instead built up an excel macro to make the steps I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants to see it (and maybe so I can find it again in the future). The macros I am using to sort, format, add formulas, split to workbooks, and lock are below. This is all cobbled together, it works but it could be more efficient and clean, will come back around to that in the future.

```
Sub AddContentHeader()
Range("$E$1").Value = "HEADER TITLE" 'Repeat for each header needed

End Sub

Sub FormatTxtHead() 'Keeping all for the variance
Range("A1:N1").Font.Bold = True
Range("A1:N1").WrapText = True
Range("A1:N2814").Font.Size = 11 'Adjust to full data range
Range("A1:N2814").Font.Name = "Calibri" 'Adjust to full data range
Range("A1:N2814").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Adjust to full data range
Range("A1:N1").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
Range("K1:N1").Interior.Color = RGB(105, 139, 105) 'Green
Range("F1:G1").Interior.Color = RGB(224, 238, 224) 'Light Green
Range("I1").Interior.Color = RGB(224, 238, 224) 'Light Green
Range("A1:E1").Interior.Color = RGB(162, 181, 205) 'Blue
Range("H1").Interior.Color = RGB(162, 181, 205) 'Blue
Range("J1").Interior.Color = RGB(162, 181, 205) 'Blue
End Sub

Sub AddFormulas()
Range("G1:G2814").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Range("I1:I2814").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Range("H2").Formula = "=E2*G2"
Range("H2").Copy
Range("H2:H2814").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'Adjust to full data range
Range("H2:H2814").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
Range("J2").Formula = "=E2*I2"
Range("J2").Copy
Range("J2:J2814").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'Adjust to full data range
Range("J2:J2814").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
Range("K2").Formula = "=G2+I2"
Range("K2").Copy
Range("K2:K2814").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'Adjust to full data range
Range("K2:K2814").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Range("L2").Formula = "=E2+H2"
Range("L2").Copy
Range("L2:L2814").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'Adjust to full data range
Range("L2:L2814").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
Range("M2").Formula = "=L2/2080"
Range("M2").Copy
Range("M2:M2814").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'Adjust to full data range
Range("M2:M2814").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
Range("N2").Formula = "=J2+L2"
Range("N2").Copy
Range("N2:N2814").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll) 'Adjust to full data range
Range("N2:N2814").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
End Sub

Sub DropDownSelectList()

'replace "F2:F2814" with the cell range you want to insert the drop down list
With Range("F2:F2814").Validation
.Delete
'replace "New,Low,Below,Met,Exceed,Super" with list or the range the validation data is in.
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="New,Low,Below,Met,Exceed,Super"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
End Sub


Sub SplitToWorksheets()
Dim ColHead As String
Dim ColHeadCell As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long 'row index on Fan Data sheet
Dim Lrow As Integer 'row index on individual destination sheet
Dim Dsheet As Worksheet 'destination worksheet
Dim Fsheet As Worksheet 'fan data worksheet (assumed active)
Again:
ColHead = InputBox("Enter Column Heading", "Identify Column", [c1].Value)
If ColHead = "" Then Exit Sub
Set ColHeadCell = Rows(1).Find(ColHead, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If ColHeadCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Heading not found in row 1"
GoTo Again
End If
Set Fsheet = ActiveSheet
iCol = ColHeadCell.Column
'loop through values in selected column
For iRow = 2 To Fsheet.Cells(65536, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
If Not SheetExists(CStr(Fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)) Then
Set Dsheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
Dsheet.Name = CStr(Fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)
Fsheet.Rows(1).Copy
With Dsheet.Rows(1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
Else
Set Dsheet = Worksheets(CStr(Fsheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value))
End If
Lrow = Dsheet.Cells(65536, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
Fsheet.Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=Dsheet.Rows(Lrow + 1)
Next iRow
End Sub

Function SheetExists(SheetId As Variant) As Boolean
' This function checks whether a sheet (can be a worksheet,
' chart sheet, dialog sheet, etc.) exists, and returns
' True if it exists, False otherwise. SheetId can be either
' a sheet name string or an integer number. For example:
' If SheetExists(3) Then Sheets(3).Delete
' deletes the third worksheet in the workbook, if it exists.
' Similarly,
' If SheetExists("Annual Budget") Then Sheets("Annual Budget").Delete
' deletes the sheet named "Annual Budget", if it exists.
Dim sh As Object
On Error GoTo NoSuch
Set sh = Sheets(SheetId)
SheetExists = True
Exit Function
NoSuch:
If Err = 9 Then SheetExists = False Else Stop
End Function


Sub InsertFormula()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    NxtRw1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 2
    With Cells(NxtRw1, "B")
     .Formula = "Total Pool"
     .Interior.Color = RGB(162, 181, 205) 'Blue
     .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    NxtRw2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 2
    With Cells(NxtRw2, "C")
     .Formula = "=SUM(E1:E" & NxtRw2 - 1 & ")*.03"
     .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
     .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    NxtRw3 = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 2
    With Cells(NxtRw3, "D")
     .Formula = "Remaining"
     .Interior.Color = RGB(162, 181, 205) 'Blue
     .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    NxtRw4 = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 2
    With Cells(NxtRw4, "E")
     .Formula = "=(SUM(E1:E" & NxtRw4 - 1 & ")*.03)-((SUM(N1:N" & NxtRw4 - 1 & ")-SUM(E1:E" & NxtRw4 - 1 & ")))"
     .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
     .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
     .Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next
End Sub



Sub RemoveColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete 'Set to data range

Next ws
End Sub

Sub CopyPasteKey()
Dim i As Long
For Each ws In Worksheets
  With ws
  i = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row 'Set Range to longest column in key
  Sheets("Sheet420").Range("A1:I15").Copy .Range("A" & i + 2)
  End With
Next ws
End Sub


Sub protect_all_sheets()
top:
    pass = InputBox("password?")
    repass = InputBox("Verify Password")
    If Not (pass = repass) Then
      MsgBox "you made a boo boo"
      GoTo top
    End If

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).ProtectContents = True Then GoTo oops
    Next

    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        s.Protect Password:=pass
    Next
    Exit Sub

oops:
    MsgBox "I think you have some sheets that are already protected. Please unprotect all sheets then run this Macro."
End Sub



Sub Split_To_Workbook()
'Working in 2013/2016
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim myOutlook As Object
    Dim myMailItem As Object
    Dim mySubject As String
    Dim myPath As String
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


    'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Create new folder to save the new files in
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = "C:\PATH\" & Sourcewb.Name & " " & DateString
    MkDir FolderName
    'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
    For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets
        'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
        If sh.Visible = -1 Then
            sh.Copy
            'Set Destwb to the new workbook
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2016
                    If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                        MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                        GoTo GoToNextSheet
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    End If
                End If
            End With
            'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
            If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
                With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Cells.Copy
                    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Cells(1).Select
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
            'Save the new workbook, email it, and close it
            With Destwb
                .SaveAs FolderName _
                      & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr, _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
            End With
            myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
            With Destwb
                .Close False
            End With

        End If
GoToNextSheet:
    Next sh
    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub


'May want to open a new workbook to run this. You will have to accept every file
Sub YE_SetPassword()

    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    strPath = "C:\Users\FOLDER\" 'UPDATE TO DESTINATION FOLDER
    strFile = Dir(strPath)

    ' Add Excel File Names to the variable colfiles
    While strFile <> ""
        colFiles.Add strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Wend

    ' Start reading colfiles collection and open workbooks one at a time
    If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = colFiles(i)
                Application.Workbooks.Open strPath & colFiles(i)
            Workbooks(colFiles(i)).Activate

    ' Once workbook is open search for Sheet2 and Sheet3 and if they are there, delete them
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
        ws.Delete
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
        ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Check cell value of A2 for Sup Name the assign a password based on that value
        x = Range("A2").Value
        Select Case x
    Case "LOOKUP VALUE"
        pw = "PASSWORD TO LOCK WITH"
        End Select

        ' Save the workbook with unique password
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            strPath & colFiles(i), FileFormat:= _
                xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:=pw, WriteResPassword:="", _
                ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```